# Django view for both AJAX and normal request

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm starting with new project where there will be used to delete product using AJAX, but sometimes with normal request. What do you think about this view? I'm trying to make it as universal as possible.

```
@login_required
@require_POST
def delete_products(request):
    products_ids = request.POST.getlist('products_ids')
    deleted = Product.objects.filter(id__in=products_ids,user=request.user).delete()
    if request.is_ajax():
        return JsonResponse({'success':True,
                             'ids':[x.id for x in deleted]})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next') or '/')
```